# Definition of "small object" in C++ when passing arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

In the new "C++ Programming Language" book(and probably in previous versions), Bjarne Stroustrup recommends:

> 1. Use pass-by-value for small objects
> 2. Use pass-by-const-reference to pass large values that you don't need to modify.
> 3. ...

Is there a common accepted definition for small objects when it comes to arguments passing?
For example it's obvious that any object smaller than the address size is a small object, but what about the objects that have 2, 3, 4 times the size of an address? Are they considered small and should be passed by value?

As a sample code to work on:

```
struct Vector {float x, y, z;};
```

Should I prefer:

```
void do_something_with_vector(Vector v){...}
```

or:

```
void do_something_with_vector(const Vector& v){...}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25273958/596781

Comment: I think "small object" is an object which size less or equial than reference (creating a reference to it does not make sense)

Comment: Seems to have 2 duplicates..

Comment: The true answer is far more subtle. It may sometimes be faster to pass your Vector by value, as it will make it easier for the compiler to put its members in registers inside the function, as it knows they cannot change. My personal suggestion is to pass by const reference, and come back to this if you have a performance problem.

Comment: @YuriS.Cherkasov I'm pretty sure that that's not the answer.  On many architectures, a `double` will be larger than a reference, but it is almost always preferable to pass a single `double` by value.

Comment: How did this get marked as a duplicate.  The question is totally unrelated to the question cited as above.

Comment: @James Of course that statement is applicable to classes, not basic types

Comment: @Justin: I added it as another option!

Answer (score 1):

Small objects are anything the size of or smaller than a pointer. If you pass something larger, like the  Vector struct in your example, then it will be copied and that's just a waste :-)