# Print the value of template

Tags: c++, templates

So, I just want to make this function:

```
template<typename T>
void printWithEndl(T)
{
    std::cout << T << "\n";
}
```

but I got this error on the line:

```
std::cout << T << "\n";
```

I wonder: how can I *cout* the value of T?

Comment: You forgot to give the variable a name.  The type alone is not enough.

Comment: You could do `typeid(T).name()` but it's not necessarily going to give you anything useful.

Comment: I think he wants to print the type used in that instance of the template. "int", "char", or whatever was used for instantiating. Not sure if possible in standard C++.

Comment: Also you'd have to overload the << operator for any type you pass there in.

Comment: Oh, I cannot believe I made such a rookie mistake, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should name the variable you're passing to `printWithEndl`, and `cout` that name:

```
template<typename T>
void printWithEndl(T msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << "\n";
}
```

If you're using this to print complex objects, you're probably better off [passing a reference to const](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627166/2449857):

```
template<typename T>
void printWithEndl(const T& msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Differing variable and type names by case is considered a bad programming practice.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews to what from OP's answer are you referring?

Comment: In your answer, you have a data type `T` and a variable `t`.  One of these should be a different name.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thanks! I haven't caught that from your previous comment