# Passing const to function with non-const parameter

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I'am following accelerated C++ book but i'am confused with the source code they provide. My confusion  involves functions `double grade(double midterm, double final, const vector<double>& hw)` and `double median(vector<double> vec)`.
It says in the comment that the `grade` function does not copy it's argument because the `median` function does. Why is that so?
From my understanding you can't pass const to non-const since what would require write-access.

Here's the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::domain_error;
using std::endl;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;
using std::setprecision;
using std::sort;
using std::streamsize;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

// compute the median of a `vector<double>'
// note that calling this function copies the entire argument `vector'
double median(vector<double> vec)
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    typedef std::vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
#else
    typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
#endif

    vec_sz size = vec.size();
    if (size == 0)
        throw domain_error("median of an empty vector");

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    vec_sz mid = size/2;

    return size % 2 == 0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid-1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
}

// compute a student's overall grade from midterm and final exam grades and homework grade
double grade(double midterm, double final, double homework)
{
    return 0.2 * midterm + 0.4 * final + 0.4 * homework;
}

// compute a student's overall grade from midterm and final exam grades
// and vector of homework grades.
// this function does not copy its argument, because `median' does so for us.
double grade(double midterm, double final, const vector<double>& hw)
{
    if (hw.size() == 0)
        throw domain_error("student has done no homework");
    return grade(midterm, final, median(hw));
}

// read homework grades from an input stream into a `vector<double>'
istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
    if (in) {
        // get rid of previous contents
        hw.clear();

        // read homework grades
        double x;
        while (in >> x)
            hw.push_back(x);

        // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
        in.clear();
    }
    return in;
}


int main()
{
    // ask for and read the student's name
    cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello, " << name << "!" << endl;

    // ask for and read the midterm and final grades
    cout << "Please enter your midterm and final exam grades: ";
    double midterm, final;
    cin >> midterm >> final;

    // ask for the homework grades
    cout << "Enter all your homework grades, "
            "followed by end-of-file: ";

    vector<double> homework;

    // read the homework grades
    read_hw(cin, homework);

    // compute and generate the final grade, if possible
    try {
        double final_grade = grade(midterm, final, homework);
        streamsize prec = cout.precision();
        cout << "Your final grade is " << setprecision(3)
             << final_grade << setprecision(prec) << endl;
    } catch (domain_error) {
        cout << endl << "You must enter your grades.  "
            "Please try again." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between const reference and normal parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627166/difference-between-const-reference-and-normal-parameter)

Comment: The important thing is the comment "note that calling this function copies the entire argument `vector'" - this copies aconst vector. So in no way changes the original const & vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
return grade(midterm, final, median(hw));
```

`hw` here is a const reference to a vector, which is being passed to `median`. While it is true that you can't modify an object through a const reference, you can still make a copy of it through a const reference. So, since `median` requires to change the `vector` (by sorting it), it makes a copy for itself (the copy will be implicitly created under the hood) and sorts it instead.

Comment: that's the bit i was missing, so median is allowed to make a copy of the const.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is that so? From my understanding you can't pass const to
>   non-const since what would require write-access.

Yes and no, it is correct that you can't write to a `const` variable but that's not what's happening here.

```
return grade(midterm, final, median(hw));
```

The call here to `median` does the work for us. `median` expects a `std::vector` and the compiler passes it one under the hood. It copies over the vector referenced by the `const &` and passes that copy to `median`. Remember, the compiler only needs read access to copy, not write, which is exactly what `hw` gives us.