# What are constant members in C++?

Tags: c++

```
class Foo
{
public:
    const int a;
    const int* x;
    int* const y;
    Foo() : a{ 0 }, y{ new int(20) } {
        x = new int(10);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    // f.a = 100; // cannot
    f.x = new int(100);
    // f.y = new int(100); // cannot

}
```

When `const int a` is defined as fields of a class,
it is called a constant member. It must be initialized in the initializer list and cannot be changed afterwards.

How about `const int* x` (which is the same as `int const* x`) and `int* const y`? Which one should be called as a constant member? If "constant member" is defined as field that must be initialized in the initializer list and cannot be changed afterwards, then the constant member is `y` rather than `x`. Am I wrong here?

## Edit

According to IntelliSense, `y` is a constant member.

[image]

OK. I am sure I am not wrong. I will delete this question shortly. Thank you for your participation!

Comment: @reece Please don't attempt to answer questions with comments. It prevents people from down voting incorrect information.

Comment: You're not wrong. `int* const y` declares a constant pointer

Comment: I am actually trying to counter the following [post](https://github.com/huihut/interview/issues/78#issuecomment-814899414).

Comment: Semi-related: [Handy tool](https://cdecl.org/)

Comment: I don't know if the term "constant member" is specified or if it's opinion based.

Comment: `const` and "constant" mean two different things. For example, `const int const_but_not_constant = rand();`

Comment: Side note: What makes a class like this really annoying is the assignment operator effectively becomes impossible. You can make a custom assignment operator that does nothing with `const` members, but if you `a = b;` and `a` and `b` don't have the same values in the `const` members, weird smurf is almost guaranteed to happen sooner or later.

Comment: @KeithThompson https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv: "const - defines that the type is constant."

Comment: @MoneySetsYouFree: The comment is wrong. A pointer to const data can be modified. A const pointer cannot be modified.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes. I agree with yours.

Comment: @ThomasSablik That's not what the standard says, and IMHO that wording on cppreference.com should be corrected. `const` means read-only. "constant" refers to something that can be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "const int* x" is a (non-const) pointer to a const int.  Since x is non-const, it need not be initialized upon construction.

Here are some examples:

```
class C
{
public:
    C() :
      const_int(1),
      const_int_again(2),
      const_ptr_to_non_const_int(nullptr),
      const_ptr_to_const_int(nullptr)
    {}

private:
    const int const_int;
    int const const_int_again;
    
    const int* ptr_to_const_int; // Doesn't need initialized
    int const* ptr_to_const_int_again; // Doesn't need initialized

    int* const const_ptr_to_non_const_int;
    const int* const const_ptr_to_const_int;
    int const* const const_ptr_to_const_int_again;
};
```

You may find the [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org) website helpful.

Comment: Since it's a c++ question - would be good to add references too - or link to one of the other good answers (e.g. see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627166/difference-between-const-reference-and-normal-parameter)

Comment: And a `T * const * const` vs a `T const * *`