# Why I can pass a number to function which accepts const reference? (C++)

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I'm new to C++, while I'm learning pass by reference I realized that I can't create a reference to a number directly, it has to be a variable. But if I define a function which accepts const reference, I can pass numbers in it.

```
int SumVal(const int& a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

**As far as I understand,** I can pass a number directly like `SumVal(1, 2)` if the function declared with a **const reference** because I'll **NOT** be able to change the reference so the **number**(or variable) no matter what. The compiler knows this and doesn't complain about it.

But if I define it with normal reference like `int SumVal(int& a, int b)` I have the chance to change the passed variable inside the function so If I pass a number into this function, the compiler will complain about this.

So I would like to ask that my approach is correct or non-sense.

Thank you for your comments in advance.

*(You can also check it out [CB Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/cb-bailey)'s [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627535/7630160) about pass by reference/value difference)*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826897/why-not-non-const-reference-to-temporary-objects This might be a better duplicate, with some of the philosophy behind why you can pass rvalues to functions expecting a const lvalue reference.

Comment: Ahh I couldn't find how to describe it more simple actually, thank you for mentioning the old questions @NathanPierson I'll check it out. I just understand it's the same thing with `const int& x = 1` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's because a const reference can bind to an r-value, but normal reference can't

Comment: This is the rule. What OP has is the explanation of the rule, and it is correct.